# Add rows to dataframe from another dataframe, based on a vector

Tags: r

I'd like to add rows to a dataframe based on a vector within the dataframe. Here are the dataframes (df2 is the one I'd like to add rows to; df1 is the one I'd like to take the rows from):

```
ID=c(1:5)
x=c(rep("a",3),rep("b",2))
y=c(rep(0,5))
df1=data.frame(ID,x,y)
df2=df1[2:4,1:2]
df2$y=c(5,2,3)

df1
  ID x y
1  1 a 0
2  2 a 0
3  3 a 0
4  4 b 0
5  5 b 0

df2
  ID x y
2  2 a 5
3  3 a 2
4  4 b 3
```

I'd like to add to df2 any rows that aren't in df1, based on the ID vector. so my output dataframe would look like this:

```
 ID x y
  1 b 0
  5 b 0
  2 a 5
  3 a 2
  4 b 3
```

Can anyone see a way of doing this neatly, please? I need to do it for a lot of dataframes, all with different numbers of rows. I've tried using merge or rbind but I haven't been able to work out how to do it based on the vector.

Thank you!

Comment: Please don't forget to check the answer that solved your problem so that other users can quickly find a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

A solution with dplyr:

```
bind_rows(df2,anti_join(df1,df2,by="ID"))

#  ID x y
#1  2 a 5
#2  3 a 2
#3  4 b 3
#4  1 a 0
#5  5 b 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
missingIDs <-  which(!df1$ID %in% df2$ID) #check which df1 ID's are not in df2, see function is.element()
df.toadd <- df1[missingIDs,] #define the data frame to add to df2
result <- rbind(df.toadd, df2) #use rbind to add it
result

  ID x y
1  1 a 0
5  5 b 0
2  2 a 5
3  3 a 2
4  4 b 3
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this one-liner?

```
rbind(df2, df1[!df1$ID %in% df2$ID,])

  ID x y
2  2 a 5
3  3 a 2
4  4 b 3
1  1 a 0
5  5 b 0
```

Comment: Was always wondering about the difference between df[condition] and df[which(condition)]... I guess these are equivalent but to be sure I always prefer to use which...

Comment: For simple indexing these are the same - you don't need which() in this case. However, if you wanted to use the indices for other operations, e.g. beyond simple indexing, you might have to resort to which() or match() depending on your goals in order to get the exact placements within your vector.